# exception in downloading file from google drive

Tags: java

I am new In android development and working on a project in which i wish to download my excel file saved on google drive through google drive api.
but i am getting error 403 insufficient permissions.
i got stuck here but did not found any error.please help me and thanks in advance.

```
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    Drive mService = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
            .setApplicationName("Drive API Android deldata")
            .build();
    mService.files().export(fileId, "text/csv")
            .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: please please please help me

Comment: Looks like you don't have permissions to access the file (with `fileId`)  you are requesting.

Comment: what should i do to provide permission to access file with fileId.By the way thanx for this help

Comment: Please provide the logic that builds mCredential